# Search for value from SQL Server comma-separated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I need to search for value '117' that exists in a column that stores values like `'11,118,117'`. What's the right query to do that?

Comment: The right way to do this is to fix your design. Storing delimited values is not the right way to store data. It violates 1NF.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.. split the values out into a list and then select from that list

```
declare @variable varchar(20) = '11,118,117' 

declare @your_search varchar(10) = 117

select * from string_split (@variable,',')
where [value] = @your_search
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE CHARINDEX(',117,', ',' + ColumnName + ',') > 0
```

*Please up-vote the answer. Thanks!*

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE ColumnName LIKE '117,%'
OR ColumnName LIKE '%,117,%'
OR ColumnName LIKE '%,117'
```

Comment: This can return false positives also. Things like 1177 or 2117.